# Can we host a dynamic web app on github pages?

Tags: .net, angular, github

I'm using .Net 7 for backend and angular for frontend. I'm able to see all the code of my client side when published through github pages, however i'm not able to see the responses where controller is getting called (getting 404). I've placed all the dlls in the same place where other client side js are present. Is there any way we can get this running?

Comment: no, you can't host .net apps on ghpages. it can only serve files contents that you put there, it doesn't run any code on any language

Answer (score 1):

You cannot host any services using GitHub actions. GitHub pages can only serve static files (HTML, CSS, JS) and other media types supported by modern browsers.

But there is a hack around this. You can port your code to be used with a  framework like Blazor which generates WASM files. These static files can be easily run inside browser engines.

https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-aspnet-blazor-webassembly-to-github-pages